# yield in Rails versus yield in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, erb, yield

I'm confused about whether or not `yield` in Ruby and `yield` in Rails (specifically in views/templates) are the same entity or they're two different things which act differently depending on the context.

When I think about `yield` in Ruby, this usage comes to mind:

```
def some_method
  yield 123
end

some_method { |a| a + 1 } # => 124
```

When using ERB templates in Rails, though, `yield` is used to render the views specific to the current controller/action or to render content specified through `provide` or `content_for`.

Is this the same `yield`, or does the Rails version just happen to be different functionality with the same name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the same thing. A block is passed to the layout method that will render the document body when called.

`yield` is actually a keyword in Ruby. It is possible to define a method named "yield" (Enumerator does this, for example), but whenever you see `yield` without a receiver, it will always be the same keyword that passes control to a block.

Comment: So the block that is passed to the layout method is the one that looks at the argument it receives and if it's the name of something that has been provided it shows that, otherwise it renders the view corresponding to the action?

Comment: @GabrieleCirulli: Yes, that's basically it as I understand it.